# Good PHP Ide for debugging Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, debugging, ide

I need a PHP ide for debugging my codeigniter website. I tried PhpStorm, Sublime, PhpEd and Netbeans with no success. Weird problems each time.

**I just need an IDE to set a breakpoint and see the value of variables.**

I'm tired of googling every day. Is there any stright forward way?

Thanks

Comment: Whats wrong with PhpStorm? I have been using it for years

Comment: I could not configure PhpStorm to use XAMP web server and debug. How can I do this?

Comment: That's very simple to do, am posting it as a answer.

Comment: Thanks @andre, I'm waiting...

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to configure PhpStorm to use XAMPP as the web-server and how to install the debugger.

1. The first thing you need to do is to configure a debugger in your php.ini. Am currently using Xdebugger, if you use this one then just follow these easy instruction [click here](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php). Copy the info form `php_info()` and paste it into that white box. Then download the *.dll file they give you (for windows) and paste to the folder they ask you to.
2. The second thing you need to do is to configure the PHP interpreter. Follow the images.

   [image: Click on file and then settings]

Click on PHP and then the browse button in the interpreter section.
[image]

Click on the plus sign and then other local
[image]

Get the PHP home path e.g `/xampp/php/`
[image]

Then test it, you should be able to use with the browser and in the console (if your only doing stuff with PHP)
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Now I can debug a simple PHP code. but not codeigniter. When I add a breakpoint on a Controller class or View file, it just does not work.

Comment: I'm using PHPStorm 8.0.2. Is it incompatible with Codeigniter?

Comment: How is it incompatible?

Comment: I don't know. This is a guess. I cannot debug Codeigniter because all of them are classs and I cannot debuf methods of class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try something new, Try [Cloud9](https://c9.io).

- Online IDE (I love this)
- you can setup project from FTP
- can sync with GitHub, BitBucket,
- can debug/Run

I need https for some of my project testing, thats why I searched and found this.

hope this help.

Comment: Thanks. Looks nice. But I don't access internet all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [Codelobster](http://www.codelobster.com).
It has free PHP debugger and special plug-in for CodeIgniter autocomplete.